# Creating groups in single layer legend

Tags: print-composer, legend, layouts

I am finishing a geologic map. I have all geologic polygons in a single layer.

I want that the legend shows the geologic polygons separated by age and that each group to have a header stating the age.

One thing that worked is select the polygons from the same layer and save the selected polygons as a new layer. Another thing that worked is creating separate legends for each age.

I wonder if there is a more simple way to do it in the print composer?

I am using Qgis 3.10 OSgeo4w on win10 64 bits

Comment: As the procedure will be different depending on software (and even software version) you won't get any answer unless you edit your question to add these information....